# Trigger two divs while hovering over one

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, hover

I have two divs like so and they are placed in the footer of my website :

[divs in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sMtq.png)

And here is my code :

```
.upNextCard{
  /* Rectangle 68 */

  position: absolute;
  width: 214.29px;
  height: 255.69px;
  margin-left:300px;
  margin-top:139px;
  background-color:#E0B21C;
  transform: rotate(-12.08deg);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  pointer-events: visible;

}

.upNextCard:hover {
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.upNextBanner{
  /* Rectangle 69 */
  position: absolute;
  width: 65.31px;
  height: 47.17px;
  background: #FE9C9C;
  transform: rotate(-12.45deg);
  margin-left: 400px;
  margin-top: 98px;
  pointer-events: visible;

}
```

Is there a way I can trigger both by hovering over the big box?

Comment: Please dont use Image provides code that we can test the code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just chain them for a hover on the big box.

.bigbox:hover .upNextBanner{
Etc....
}

.bigbox:hover .upNextCard{
....
}

Comment: That did the trick! Since the divs are in the footer I just did footer:hover .upNextBanner{
  margin-top:80px;
}  // Thank you so much!

Comment: Well there you go, if only everything was this simpel :)

Comment: Please mark the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you post you html code to see the relation amongst divs

look at this https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

it may help you

Comment: My bad - hope this fiddle works for you :https://jsfiddle.net/5opm43dj/#&togetherjs=9iJPJuyhzG